# Fabric + Appsee with Ad Hoc / Release API Keys

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I’m using Fabric, and porting my existing Appsee integration over (from Cocoapods). I can’t find a way to tell Fabric to use my two separate API keys for my Ad Hoc and Release builds, everything’s being piped through to live at the moment since that’s the key in its `plist` entry.

Anyone done this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now - there is no way to do this through Fabric. The only way is to replace the call:

`[Fabric with:Appsee]`

to:

`[Appsee start:@"apikey"]` and specify the different API keys manually.

We are working with the Fabric team to improve this.